# XNA Windows Phone 8 Project Template does not complete in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, xna

I'm confused when trying to create mobile game with Visual Studio 2012 and XNA. I use Windows Phone 8 with Visual Studio 2012 Express from installation package from Windows site.
When I create a project, there are only 2 templates, content pipeline extension library and empty content project. How I make my Visual Studio 2012 applied XNA template? I have tried to install XNA Game Studio and it does not make my Visual Studio 2012 have complete XNA template.
Any suggestion? Forgot, I use Windows 8 as OS.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the Windows Phone 8 SDK you should start a new Windows Phone 8 Xaml app with XNA. It's not under the XNA Game Studio 4.0 category where you might be expecting it to be. It's under the Windows Phone category:

[image: Start new Windows Phone App]

Check out the [tutorial on the MSDN website to get started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198548%28v=xnagamestudio.42%29.aspx).